# Fetch previous row in MySQL using C APIs

Tags: mysql, c

I am using `C-MySQL API`s to navigate through the fetched rows of MySQL.

I use `MYSQL_RES    *f` to retrieve result for a particular query and then I am able to fetch one row at a time using `mysql_fetch_row(f)`.

The problem is that say just now I fetched 4th row using `mysql_fetch_row(f)` but next I want is that if a specific condition is true then I should be able to fetch 2nd row else I can go through normal routine and fetch 5th row.

I tried using a temporary `MYSQL_RES  *temp`   which will be initialized as

```
temp=f;
```

and then whenever I wish to rollback I can use

```
f=temp;
```

But that's not working as both of them are pointing at same thing. I also tried

```
*temp=*f;
```

and then whenever I wish to rollback I can use

```
*f=*temp;
```

But that generates a segmentation fault.

Comment: Did you try filling temp using memcpy -- `memcpy(temp, f, sizeof(*f))` ?

Comment: Thank you for suggesting but it also generates a Segmentation fault.

Comment: Post your source, please?

Comment: The source code is quite big and might consume some your time but as you wish ..

um sorry can you please tell me how can I attach files in the comment as it is not allowing me to paste the code saying its too big for a comment